# ignore #,\,/, uppercase,$ in mysql select query

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am populating all usernames in a dropdown list. I want to ignore usernames containing any of these `#`, `\`, `/`, `uppercase`, `$`. I am Executing this query, but it still displays records with `\`, for example ad\name.

```
select account_name from dba_account where CAST(account_name  AS BINARY) RLIKE '[a-z]' 
and account_name not like '%#%' and account_name not like '%$%' and account_name not like 
'%/%' limit 50;
```

Any suggestions????

Thank You...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  account_name 
FROM
  dba_account 
WHERE 
  CAST(account_name  AS BINARY) RLIKE '[a-z]' 
  AND account_name NOT RLIKE '[#$\\\\/]'
LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: hey it still displays that record: ad\names

Comment: @Aashil Are you sure you're using the correct query? I've made a change to the answer a minute ago. Try again.

Comment: yes...it's still showing that..i don't understand why...and it is also showing records with `#`..

Comment: @Aashil The `\ ` must be double-escaped (i.e. not `\\ `, but `\\\\ `). It's in [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like). Also mySQL's `LIKE` does not seem to support chracter classes (square brackets). `RLIKE` should be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your query

```
select account_name from dba_account where CAST(account_name  AS BINARY) RLIKE '[a-z]' and account_name not like '%#%' and account_name not like '%$%' and account_name not like '%/%' limit 50;
```

doesn't contain logic to exclude backslashes.